# No consigo consumir un servicio Web con jQuery; responde Requested page not found [404]

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net

Este es un fragmento del webservice:

```
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)],   
[System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)], 
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService])
public class ClientServei : System.Web.Services.WebService
{
    [WebMethod]
    public List<Client> GetClient()
    {
        List<Client> Listclient = new List<Client>();
        Listclient.Add(new Client() { Nombre = "OSCAR", Apellido = "PUIG", Edad = 30 });
        Listclient.Add(new Client() { Nombre = "JORDI", Apellido = "FERRER", Edad = 31 });
        Listclient.Add(new Client() { Nombre = "MIQUEL", Apellido = "MAR", Edad = 31 });

        return Listclient;
    }
}
```

Y esta es la función click de jQuery que utilizo para llamar la función AJAX:

```
$("#prova").click(function () {    
    $.ajax({
               url: "ClientServei.asmx/GetClient",
               data: "{}",
               dataType: "json",
               type: "POST",
               contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
               success: function (data) {
               alert("success");
            },
            error: function (response) {
                alert("error");
            },
            failure: function (response) {
                 alert("arriva failure");
            }
      });
});
```

He capturado los errores en el alert y obtengo: `"Requested page not found [404]"`.

**¿Cuál puede ser la causa de que este webservice no se consuma correctamente?**

Comment: ¿Qué devuelve el error?, ¿que estado de HTTP?, de ser posible influyenos una captura de transferencia que puede ver en el Network panel de Chrome o Firefox.

Comment: He capurado los errores en el alert y me da el mítico: "Requested page not found [404]" al clicar al button que invoca el ajax.

Comment: Esa es la respuesta a tu solución, busca por que ocasiona el 404.

Comment: Mi primera pregunta es, porque a estas alturas del camino no implementas el webservice mejor como un REST Api utilizando ASP.Net webAPI ?

Comment: ¿Qué errores hay en la consola de JavaScript?¿Aparece algún mensaje por el `alert`?¿Está ClientServei.asmx en la misma ruta de la página que la llama? A esta pregunta le falta información importante para determinar qué está fallando y por qué.

Comment: @JuanK Estoy aprendiendo MVC5, antes prefiero asegurar que me funciona, luego siempre puedo intentar de implementarlo con las herramientas del Framework..

Comment: @Xavier el tema es que si hay algo que tiene que ver con MVC es WebAPI, WebMethods era lo que se recomendaba usar en ASP.Net para web services antes de que existiera webAPI. Solo recomendaría su uso para conectarse o extender aplicaciones legacy (viejitas)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vale el problema era que devolvia una lista directamente, en lugar de devolver un json y la función ajax no lo reconocia. Aquí dejo la solución:

```
public List<Client> GetClient()
{
    List<Client> Listclient = new List<Client>();
    Listclient.Add(new Client() { Nombre = "OSCAR", Apellido = "PUIG", Edad = 30 });
    Listclient.Add(new Client() { Nombre = "JORDI", Apellido = "FERRER", Edad = 31 });
    Listclient.Add(new Client() { Nombre = "MIQUEL", Apellido = "MAR", Edad = 31 });

    JavaScriptSerializer jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();

        string resultat_Json = jss.Serialize(Listclient);

        return resultat_Json;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

**"Requested page not found [404]"** es bastante claro algo esta mal en la URL o no hay acceso a la misma, intenta usando la url completa en la llamada al servicio

```
$("#prova").click(function () {

            $.ajax({
                url: "http://www.myservice.com/ClientServei.asmx/GetClient",
                data: "{}",
                dataType: "json",
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                success: function (data) {
                    alert("success");
                },
                error: function (response) {
                    alert("error");
                },
                failure: function (response) {
                    alert("arriva failure");
                }
            });
    });
```

Asegúrate de tener esto /o similar de acuerdo a la versión/ en el **web.config**.

```
<configuration>
    ...
    <system.web>
        ...
        <httpHandlers>
            <remove verb="*" path="*.asmx"/>
            <add verb="*" path="*.asmx" validate="false" 
                 type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, 
                       System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, 
                       Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
            ...
        </httpHandlers>
        ...
    </system.web>
    ...
<configuration>
```

También debes verificar mejor los errores, el alert no es muy bueno para eso, en su lugar tanto en `failure` como en `error` utiliza el output del browser para verificar los datos en mayor detalle, es más coloca allí un breakpoint desde el browser y examina el objeto response para obtener toda la información que sea posible con respecto al error.

```
console.log(response.);
```

Answer (score 1):

Xavier, primero que todo confirmar que tienes agregado el file de Jquery en tu html.

```
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
```

Luego, por lo que veo estas trabajando con C#, y al agregar un archivo de webServices, te crea código por defecto.

```
/// <summary>
/// Descripción breve de WebService1
/// </summary>
[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
[System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
// Para permitir que se llame a este servicio Web desde un script, usando ASP.NET AJAX, quite la marca de comentario de la línea siguiente. 
//[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
```

Si te fijas en la última línea del ScriptService, viene comentada por defecto para el funcionamiento de este a través de una llamada de JS, es necesario quitar el comentario.
De esta forma, indicamos que la clase contiene servicios que serán accedidos desde el cliente utilizando scripting (javascript).

Entonces finalmente debe quedar así:

```
/// <summary>
/// Descripción breve de WebService1
/// </summary>
[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
[System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
// Para permitir que se llame a este servicio Web desde un script, usando ASP.NET AJAX, quite la marca de comentario de la línea siguiente. 
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
```

Pruébalo, porque la llamada de ajax esta correcta.

Comment: Gracias por contestar @MBahamondes, ya tenia esta linea sin comentar.

Comment: que raro @Xavier, porque como te  comenté hice un proyecto con tu mismo código, tanto Jquery como c#, y me funcionó correctamente, tienes el código del Button que llamas $("#prova") ??

Comment: No creo que tenga nada que ver con el button, ya que si invoco el ajax des de por ejemplo el "$(document).ready(function () {"  ocurre lo mismo.

Answer (score 1):

El error que te esta mostrando es de que no encuentra el método `GetCliente`. Si tienes el `ClientServei.asmx/GetClient` dentro de una carpeta del proyecto (en otro nivel de directorio) entonces intenta colocarlo asi:

```
url: "/carpeta/ClientServei.asmx/GetClient"
```